# How to update UI in activity after navigating from some other activites

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities namely A, B & C. I have check in & check out dates in activity A. After setting check in & check out date in activity A, I go to activity B. Then from B to C. In C user can set check in & check out dates again before proceed. Now if user go back to activity A by pressing back (definitely through B), I want to update check in & check out dates as per changes in activity C.
What I did:

1. Create check in & check out date variable in application class & update them. Now question arise, if there are lots of variable, is this a good option?
2. Send a broadcast from activity C in case of date change. Activity A will receive it & update variables. But what if activity A get destroyed meanwhile.

Is there any good approach do it which will be good in all cases?

Thanks

Comment: yes ... either using `startActivityForResult/onActivityResult` (if such flow apply in your case) ... or just save state in Activity C to persistance store and reload it in when you would back in Activity A

Comment: Can't u manage those things using startActivityForResult();?

Comment: @Selvin & Lokesh Desai If I use startActivityForResult() then I need to check result in activity B first & then send result again to activity A. Suppose there are more activities in between like B1, B2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preference  , that help you to solve this issue So that you edit you Check in or check out date

Comment: Using share preferences will be helpful too. But it will be more helpful if I want to save it across different sessions (e.g. user exits from app & open it some another time). I am worried about one session only, from app open to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in some static variable in Utils class and access those variable in you activity A.So when you update those value from activity C,you will get new values in activity A when it is resume.